# How to handle application/octet-stream contained in MULTIPART_FORM_DATA

Tags: java, rest, jersey, multipart

I am trying to implement an REST endpoint which is able to handle the following POST:

```
-----------------------------6739772541706953700536795627
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="flowChunkNumber"

1
-----------------------------6739772541706953700536795627
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="flowChunkSize"

1048576
-----------------------------6739772541706953700536795627
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="flowCurrentChunkSize"

1474992
-----------------------------6739772541706953700536795627
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="flowTotalSize"

1474992
-----------------------------6739772541706953700536795627
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="flowIdentifier"

1474992-SAM_0391JPG
-----------------------------6739772541706953700536795627
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="flowFilename"

SAM_0391.JPG
-----------------------------6739772541706953700536795627
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="flowRelativePath"

SAM_0391.JPG
-----------------------------6739772541706953700536795627
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="flowTotalChunks"

1
-----------------------------6739772541706953700536795627
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="SAM_0391.JPG"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

Therefore, I try to leverage org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataMultiPart which looks like this:

```
  @POST
    @Path("/upload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public void uploadImage(FormDataMultiPart multiPartData).
```

At this point I'am struggeling with retrieving the actual content of Content-Type: application/octet-stream. Any suggestions how I can handle this type of content?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the `@FormDataParam` annotations

```
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public void uploadImage(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream file)
```

Or if you want to stick to using `FormDataMultiPart`, you could do something like

```
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public void uploadImage(FormDataMultiPart multiPartData) {
    FormDataBodyPart filePart = multiPartData.getField("file");
    if (filePart != null) {
        InputStream file = filePart.getEntityAs(InputStream.class);
    }
}
```

**See:**

- [Javadoc for `FormDataMultiPart`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.22.1/jersey/index.html?org/glassfish/jersey/media/multipart/FormDataMultiPart.html) to get an idea of other things you can do programmatically.

Comment: This was the piece of information that I need - thanks a lot! BTW: What is the best practice when it comes to store images in a database (BASE64?)